# Angular JS Pagination Stores Previous Filter value in $LocalStorage,

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, pagination

There is a View That Shows ALL Order records in Tabular format with 10 records in a single page

A filter is applied on paid orders option which shows filtered data on to a pop up window.

When I Close the Popup window and click on next Page of Existing table data The Filtered data for Paid Orders appears instead of ALL order records

How do I clear the $LocalStorage so that All order records are shown
I cannot share the code as its under NDA

Comment: This is probably an [x y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please Explain What do you want exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never user $window object to this kind of things go to this link and follow

https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage

use services for this kind of operation. Never use $window in your controller as it will increases leakage in your application
and make your application slow

Answer (score 0):

Clears all localstorage data.

```
$window.localStorage.clear();
```